# Issue using .Contains with application.loadedlevel/loadlevel

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm working on a script that returns to the correct scene when pressing escape.
In the DataUpgrade, Level Select, TransferData(x) it should return to StartMenu, in StartMenu it should close the game and in a Level(x) it should return to TransferData(x).
The following script has been made with help from FunctionR.

```
#pragma strict
import System;

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey ("escape")) 
    {
        var level : String = Application.loadedLevel.ToString();

        //var transferData = "TransferData";

        if(level == "StartMenu"){
            Application.Quit();
            }

        else if(level == "DataUpgrade"){
            Application.LoadLevel("StartMenu");
            }

        else if(level == "Level Select"){
            Application.LoadLevel("StartMenu");
            }

        else if(level.Contains("TransferData"))
            Application.LoadLevel("StartMenu");


        else if(level.Contains("Level"))
            Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel - 1);

        //trying this out but isn't working either
        /*else if( transferData in level)
            Application.LoadLevel("StartMenu");


        else if("Level" in level)
            Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel - 1);*/  
    }
}
```

i'm not sure why it's not working, the scenes have the correct names and have also been added to build settings.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing this line:

```
var level : String = Application.loadedLevel.ToString();
```

with

```
var level = Application.loadedLevelName;`
```

fixed the problem, everything is working now

Answer (score 1):

#### Quick Fix

This is how you fix it, and you don't need the `for` loop. I use `Contains()` to do the hard work.

```
import System;

function Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKey ("escape")) 
    {
        var level : String = Application.loadedLevel.ToString();

        if(level == "StartMenu")
            Application.Quit();

        else if(level == "DataUpgrade")
            Application.LoadLevel("StartMenu");

        else if(level == "Level Select")
            Application.LoadLevel("StartMenu");

        else if(level.Contains("TransferData")
            Application.LoadLevel("StartMenu");
     }
}
```

---

#### Smart Fix

You can also be smart and take advantage of the `OR` operator to reduce your related `if` statements.

```
else if(level == "DataUpgrade" || level == "Level Select" || level.Contains("TransferData")
    Application.LoadLevel("StartMenu");
```

---

#### Sneaky Fix

You can also be sneaky since all other cases, except one, takes you back to `StartMenu`. You can have an `else` that guarantees a return to `StartMenu`.

```
 if(Application.loadedLevel == "StartMenu")
     Application.Quit();

 else
     Application.LoadLevel("StartMenu");
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed reply, it's really great i've learned a couple things here :). I started with the Quick fix and was going to use the Smart fix after it worked but the Contains part isn't working, i will update my question with the new code.
the sneaky fix wouldn't work because there is another case that doesn't take you back to StartMenu, for example in Level1 it should return to TransferData1 and in the build settings TransferData always comes right before the Level so i used loadedLevel - 1 in this case